# Shortcuts for computing the eigenvalues of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

How would you calculate the eigenvalues of the following matrix?

$A = \begin{pmatrix} -3 & 1 & -1 \\ -7 & 5 & -1\\ -6 & 6 & -2\end{pmatrix}$ $ $ $\ \ \ \ \  $$\chi_A(\lambda) = \det(A-\lambda I)= \begin{vmatrix} -3-\lambda & 1 & -1 \\ -7 & 5-\lambda & -1\\ -6 & 6 & -2-\lambda \end{vmatrix}=\ldots =0$

I'd really like to avoid using the rule of Sarrus. This will just lead to a huge list of multiplications and finally I may even have to guess the roots of the polynomial (maybe with Vieta's Theorem) and factor them out via polynomial division. - This whole process is tedious and prone to errors so I'd like to take some shortcuts whenever I can.

Here are some shortcuts I already know, which may be used in conjunction:

- Multiplying two rows by $(-1)$ (this will not change the determinant)
- Developing the determinant via a row or column that has a lot of zeros in it (ideally just one factor) to get out linear factors of the polynomial.
- Transforming the matrix via gaussian elimination to a matrix which has more zeros in one column or row (ideally: transform it to a lower/upper triangular matrix).
- Compute the determinant via the theorem for block-diagonal matrices.

However, none of these shortcuts are useful for calculating the eigenvalues of $A$. How would you approach the computation of the determinant of the matrix of above? What other shortcuts do you have to share?

Comment: For dense matrix expanding of determinant is only method, I suppose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a start:

Add column 1 to column 2 (this doesn't change the determinant); then take out a factor from column 2; after that, add column 2 to column 3:
$$
\chi_A(\lambda)
= \begin{vmatrix} -3-\lambda & 1 & -1 \\ -7 & 5-\lambda & -1 \\ -6 & 6 & -2-\lambda\end{vmatrix}
= \begin{vmatrix} -3-\lambda & -2-\lambda & -1 \\ -7 & -2-\lambda & -1 \\ -6 & 0 & -2-\lambda\end{vmatrix}
= -(2+\lambda) \begin{vmatrix} -3-\lambda & 1 & -1 \\ -7 & 1 & -1 \\ -6 & 0 & -2-\lambda\end{vmatrix}
= -(2+\lambda) \begin{vmatrix} -3-\lambda & 1 & 0 \\ -7 & 1 & 0 \\ -6 & 0 & -2-\lambda\end{vmatrix}
= \dotsb
$$

Comment: Thanks! I didn't think of taking out a factor of a column! That's a good idea! I guess there's really no simpler way than doing it that way when the matrix is dense.

Comment: In general, you may not be able to avoid multiplying everything out. For tricks like this to work, one needs to be a bit lucky. Or the exercise needs to be rigged. ;-)